# Show commands without executing them

Tags: bash

I often interactively loop over e.g. my files and want to perform a specific operation on all of them, let's say I'd like to rename all files:

```
for file in $(ls); do mv "$file" "${file}_new"; done
```

This works fine. But before invoking this command, I'd like to see what it actually does, so I would add an echo in front

```
for file in $(ls); do echo mv "$file" "${file}_new"; done
```

it then shows me all the commands it would invoke. If I'm happy with them, I remove the `echo` and execute it.

However, when the commands are a bit more subtle maybe including pipes or more than one command, this doesn't work anymore. Of course I could use `'` so the special characters don't get interpreted, but then I don't have parameter expansion. I could also escape the special characters, but this would get very tedious.

My question is, what's the best way to do this? I've read in `man bash` about the option `-n`, which does "Read commands but do not execute them.  This may be used to  check  a  shell  script  for syntax errors. This is ignored by interactive shells." This is exactly what I need, but I need it for an interactive shell. Note that the options `-x` or `-v` do not help, as it will not only show the command, but also invoke it and then it might be too late already.

Comment: Technically, there is no way to achieve that.

Comment: Alternatively, you may *alias-empty* each command into something like `alias <command>='bash -c ""'`, so that parameters are accepted, yet nothing gets executed. You may run an *alias-emptifier* loop, execute the process you want, and later *alias-restore* the commands -- restoring their functionality.

Comment: By the way, using `for file in $(ls)` is sacrificing a child (process) for no good reason.  Why not use `for file in *`?

Comment: The real problem with `for file in $(ls)` is that it will break for file names that contain spaces.

Comment: What's the proper way to do this if I'm not in the directory where I want to make the `ls`?

Comment: `for f in /path/to/files/*` or generally any wildcard expression which will uniquely identify your files.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[This](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2012-11/msg00010.html) thread would tell you why the option to show commands instead of executing those (a.k.a *dry run*) would never be implemented for `bash`.

Refer to the response from [Eric Blake](http://home.comcast.net/~ericblake/):

> `>` My question is why can't such an option or be provided,
>
> A little thought would show why this will never be implemented.  What
>   would such an option output for the following:
>
> ```
> if complex_command; then
>   foo=command1
> else
>   foo=command2
> fi
> $foo args
> ```
>
> On the line for `$foo args`, there is no way to know what `$foo` expands
>   to unless you have previously executed (not just scanned) the
>   `complex_command`.  Therefore, there is no way to dry run what the final
>   results will be without running things, but running things is counter
>   to the goal of a dry run.
>
> That said, you might be interested in the `bashdb` project, which uses
>   bash hooks to provide a debugger interface where you can single-step
>   through a bash script; it's not the same as telling you what the
>   script would do, but it at least lets you control how much or little
>   of the script is actually run.

Answer (score 37):

There is no option for "dry run" as [explained by devnull](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19116083/34088) but there is a simple workaround:

```
debug=
#debug=echo

$debug mv "$file" "${file}_new"
```

If you remove the comment from the second assignment (without changing anything else), you enable "dry run" for the dangerous `mv` command.

A more elaborate approach would be to check some condition (like a command line option):

```
debug=
if [[ ...enable dry run?... ]]; then
    debug=echo
fi
```

Note: The empty assignment is only necessary when you have the option `-u` ("Treat unset variables as an error when substituting.") enabled.

**Important:** This won't work well, when your commands use redirections (because the shell will always do them before the command is even started).

Comment: What has to be assigned to revert debug into it's initiall setting, whatever that setting was? PS: For some reason it seems that debug is not available in my bash

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou `debug` is just a local variable to which I either assign nothing or a command which just prints its arguments (`echo`). To revert the effect, simply assign nothing again: `debug=`.

Answer (score 10):

There is a [github](https://github.com/p-e-w/maybe) package called maybe, here's an example:

```
$ maybe rm file
> maybe has prevented rm file from performing 1 file system operations:
>
> delete /home/user/file
>
> Do you want to rerun rm file and permit these operations? [y/N]
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually you can do this in a script

add:

```
set -x # Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.
set -n # Read commands but do not execute them
```

in the beginning  of the script

Also a good practice is to add `set -e` to exit on error

(for more reference [man set](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/seth.html))

Comment: Not working on `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)`

Comment: Working for bash from at least version 3.3. Could be a cygwin issue? also pls check 'man set'

Comment: Checked. When using the two switches together I simply get no output and no execution

Comment: if you `set -v`, you at least get output, but it doesn't show the variable substitutions as the OP would want

Answer (score 0):

With a small 'set -x' hack, I got a pleasant result:

```
{ set -x; echo "hello world" "hello" >/dev/null; set +x; } 2>&1 | sed '/set +x/d'
```

For example:

```
dry_run() {
  # dry-run on
  if ($dry_run); then
    { set -x; echo "$@" >/dev/null; set +x; } 2>&1 | sed '/set +x/d' >&2; return
  else
    "$@"
  fi
}

dry_run=true
dry_run ls -l
```