# How to verify the commands to be run by shell script

Tags: bash, shell

If I use `set -x`, then the commands are displayed just before they are executed. That way they are printed.

But I want to have a debug mode for my script where the user can actually see what commands are going to get printed but those are not executed.

I also tried using `:` (null command) to print the current command but that does not propagate the result. e.g.,

```
find /my/home -name "test*" | while read -r i;
do 
    rm -f $i
done
```

For this purpose, the out put expected is:

```
+find /my/home -name "test"
+ rm -f test1
+ rm -f test2 ...
```

and so on

Is there any way I can achieve this without repeating code (the obvious way being have 2 sections in the batch script for debug and normal mode)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show commands without executing them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115156/show-commands-without-executing-them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maybe create a wrapper function that either prints or evaluates the command you give to it:

```
#!/bin/bash

run_command () {
   printf '%q ' "$@"
   "$@"
}

run_command ls -l
run_command touch /tmp/hello
run_command rm /tmp/hello
```

This way, you prepend `run_command` to any single thing you want to do and comment the execution or the `echo` action as you wish.

You could also provide a parameter to the script that switches to either `echo` or execute mode:

```
debug_mode=$1
run_command () {
    if [ "$debug_mode" = true ]; then
        printf '%q ' "$@"
    else
        "$@"
    fi
}

run_command ...
```

Comment: Isn't the `eval` both wrong and dangerous here? I would think just `echo "$@"; "$@";` would be closer to what you would want and expect.

Comment: Oh man you are right. I knew there was something weird in the syntax. Fixed, many thanks!

Comment: `printf '%q ' "$@"; echo` would be more correct than `echo "$@"` here -- the `echo` doesn't show you the difference between `rm "some file"` and `rm "some" "file"`.

Comment: The commentary surrounding the code is now out of sync with the edited code.

Comment: Thanks for reporting, @user3439894 I just corrected it and also expanded a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Most simplest way to run preview/dryrun:

```
for f in *; do echo "these files will be removed with rm -f $f"; done
```

Comment: Lack of quotes means that this will show some filenames incorrectly. Let's say someone ran `touch '*.txt'` -- when iterating over that file, this would expand the glob and show _all_ text files in the current directory on that single line, rather than showing the literal `*.txt` name. Similarly, a name with runs of spaces or tabs would have each string of whitespace replaced with a single space.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that was easy to fix!