# Bash function to run or echo a string

Tags: bash

I've written a bash script, which creates LVM snapshots and it works great. Recently I added a function to make a dryrun, so that I can see what would happen.
To do this, my script has several constructions like this:

```sh
if [ $DRYRUN == "1" ]; then
            echo "DRYRUN: lvcreate $SNAPSHOT_SIZE -s -n $snapshotName \"$vg/$lv\""
        else
            lvcreate $SNAPSHOT_SIZE -s -n $snapshotName "$vg/$lv"
        fi
```

which is awful. I want to refactor this properly.

One way to do this is to write a function, which expects a string and this function runs the string as command, if DRYRUN isn't set or prints out the string (correctly escaped) if otherwise.
However, I have no idea how to do that.

How could this be done?
Is there any other way to improve the code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show commands without executing them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115156/show-commands-without-executing-them)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
run() {
    if (( dryrun )); then
        printf "DRYRUN:"
        printf ' %q' "$@"
        printf '\n'
    else
       "$@"
    fi
}

dryrun=1
run echo "testing testing"
```

though note that this only work with simple commands. [BashFAQ 50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) has some more info on the subject.

Another way to approach this is to override the important commands only for the dryrun:

```
if (( dryrun )); then
    lvcreate() {
        printf 'DRYRUN: %s' "${FUNCNAME[0]}"; printf ' %q' "$@"; printf '\n'
    }
    rm() {
        printf 'DRYRUN: %s' "${FUNCNAME[0]}"; printf ' %q' "$@"; printf '\n'
    }    
fi
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! Your first code snipplet works great. Just what I needed to make the script much shorter and more readable. Unfortunately I dont have the reputation to vote :-(