# Determine all dependencies of .sh scripts without running them

Tags: bash, dependencies, sh, dependency-management

Having project with 1000 of `sh/bash` scripts is there way to determine 
what libraries are used in these scripts without running them and looking for errors? 
Maybe there is a tool for this or it is possible to write script which will do it?

Comment: You mean the `sourced` files. Use a tool like awk to find the sourced files.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115156/show-commands-without-executing-them

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the exact requirement, but below might help

```
awk 'NR==1{printf "Current File : %s\n",FILENAME;}
     /^source/{print gensub(/^source[[:blank:]]*/,"",1,$0)}
     /^\./{print gensub(/^\.[[:blank:]]*/,"",1,$0)}' *.sh
```

**In short**

The above script, using gnu awk, prints the filenames and for each filename list the sourced files

Comment: Need not be just `source`d scripts. I don't know if I understood OP's question correctly, but if the script has contents like `ls a.c<newline>gcc a.c`; then `ls`, `gcc` are the dependencies of the script, which OP wants to list.

Comment: @anishsane, yes, exactly