# Bash: How to create a test mode that displays commands instead of executing them

Tags: bash, echo, io-redirection

I have a bash script that executes a series of commands, some involving redirection. See [cyrus-mark-ham-spam](https://github.com/nikkilocke/cyrus-mark-ham-spam).

I want the script to have a test mode, where all the commands run are printed instead of executing them. As you can see, I have tried to do that by just putting "echo" on the front of each command in test mode.

Unfortunately this doesn't deal with redirection - any redirections are still done, so the program leaves lots of temp files littered about the place when run in test mode.

I have tried various ways to get round this, like quoting the whole command and passing it to a function that either prints it or runs it, but either the redirections work in test mode, or they don't work in run mode.

I thought this must have come up before, and wonder if there is a known solution which does not involve every command being repeated with an if TEST round the pair?

Please note, this is NOT a duplicate of [show commands without executing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115156/show-commands-without-executing-them) because neither that question, nor its answers, covers redirection (which is the essence of this question).

Comment: IMHO it is a duplicate, because the duplicate answers your question in the negative: "It is not possible". It even explains, why this is so and it additionally offers alternative route to try with bashdb.

Answer (score 0):

I see that it is not a duplicate but there is not general solution to this. You need to look at each command separately.

As long as the command doesn't use arguments enclosed in spaces, like

```
cmd -a -b -c > filename
```

, you can quote it:

```
echo 'cmd -a -b -c > filename'
```

But real life code is more complex, sure.